# How can I stop git subtree split from un-squashing everything?

Tags: git, git-subtree

The main repo has a subdirectory that contains code from both the main repo and another repo using subtree. I squashed every merge from the other repo to keep the main repo's history clean.

Now I want to split the main repo's branch into two branches, one for each top directory. That means the subtree's prefix will change to `/`, which is okay.

I ran `git subtree split -P=subdirectory/ -b newbranch` and everything seems to be perfect except that each squash merge has turned into a full merge, bringing along all history from the other repo! Why does it do this and how can I preserve my main repo history, including only squashes from the other repo like it is today?